# Table size difference

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

I literally cannot comprehend why it does this, the size of the first td seems to absorb a portion of the size of the last td.

The id of the table is "slide-table", http://www.rickpascua.cu.cc/.

This bug or w/e it is only occurs on Firefox and IE, Chrome shows it just fine with an equally distributed size.

Any help would be much appreciated!

(I should note this only occurred after I added a few `.hide()`'s but none of them directly affect the "slide-table".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the browser determines the width of table columns based on what’s in each `td`. So in your case, the width of each column depends on the images, which are all different sizes.

You can change that in the CSS by specifying:

```
#slide-table table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

and also specifying a `width` for each column.

Or just make all the images the same width and height.

Comment: the table-layout:fixed worked just fine, the problem with specifying a width for each column is that it is dynamic and I want it to automatically resize the cells when adding or removing.

Comment: You might be able to use `width: 20%` or something like that, depending on what else you have going on in this page... why use a table at all, though? Why not just put five `<img>` tags in the div?

Comment: It would be extremely irritating if everytime I added a new cell or removed one to recalculate width's instead of having it dynamically done. the cells themselves are icons to specific slider images.